# Dual Monitor Problems

Tags: amd-radeon

I have an AMD Radeon Hd 6450 graphics card (on w7) and for some reason it wont pick up my DVI or HDMI sockets it will only use the VGA.I have a VGA-HDMI and VGA-DVI converters as both my monitors are VGA.Is there something i need to do to get these to work?or does dual monitors not work with this card?

Comment: you mean HDMI-VGA & DVI-VGA? What you actually wrote makes no sense. You can not have an analog VGA monitor on a DVI-D port. unless you have an active converter.
At least one monitor needs to be digital (DVI, HDMI for example).

Comment: With a passive converter that has a DVI-I connection, the analog signal just passes through to the graphics card that can then receive the analog signal and use it as if it was an analog connection, even through the DVI port.

Answer (score 0):

If those converters are passive like [this one](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/DVI-VGA-Adapter.jpg), make sure you select the VGA monitor on Catalyst, as the signal is still analog.
Also, on "Advanced Display Settings" make sure you select the option to detect displays automatically.

Comment: only one monitor appears on catalyst which is the primary monitor.